# Advanced Sorting Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, sorting

I'm writing an app in Javascript that uses Google maps and calculates a full route between a series of legs based off closest legs.

Say I've got 4 legs on the map, each leg has a start and end Latitude and Longitude. The user specifies which two legs are the start and end of the route. Each end of a leg can only connect to another legs start. Then the end of that leg connects to another legs start, and so on. The code determines which legs start to connect to based off the closest leg it can find.

Something like this for example (the dashed lines are the legs):

```
start-----------end  <-connector->  start----------end  <-connector->  start----------end
```

I've got an array of all of the leg coordinates, and I want to sort this array so that it follows the proper progression of connections. Then I can utilize the array to generate the connectors by linearly looping through it.

The array looks something like this:

```
[
   {start_lat: X, start_lng: X, end_lat: X, end_lng: X},
   {start_lat: X, start_lng: X, end_lat: X, end_lng: X},
]
```

Those will be the inner legs. And then I'll have the outer legs (the two legs that are the start and the end of the entire route) stored in variables:

```
var start = {end_lat: X, end_lng: X}
var end = {start_lat: X, start_lng: X}
```

As an example it might end up something like:

```
start -> array[0] -> array[1] -> end
```

Or it might end up like:

```
start -> array[1] -> array[0] -> end
```

The algorithm needs to sort the array based off the start legs end_lat,end_lng and the end legs end_lat,end_lng.

The end result will be a big route connected together with the shortest path.

I'm struggling to think of a way of writing the sorting algorithm that takes these unique factors into consideration.

It's difficult to put this into words, and I'm not really sure how I can help make it clearer, but I'll edit this post if I can think of anything useful to add. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: map]

The black lines are the legs, the red lines are the connectors I will need to generate after I've sorted the array of leg coordinates into the correct order. The generating the connectors isn't part of this algorithm, but it's just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish so you can understand the big picture. As you can see there are gaps between the legs, none of the coordinates overlap.

Comment: Not sure if you need a sorting algorithm or a shortest-path algorithm...? If you implement a shortest-path algorithm like Dijkstra's it will spit out the shortest path, then you'd just need to make sure you maintain a reference to the original locations in the array to "sort" like you want.

Comment: Maybe draw a picture? I'm having trouble understanding what you're looking to do.

Comment: mdkess I've added a picture to the main post.

WilliamGaul I think it's a combination of both?

Comment: You don't need a sorting algorithm in here. To linearly loop through the legs you don't need an array, but you need to know the connections between the legs. Depending on your actual data this is far closer to the travelling sales man problem than to a graph search. If the nearest start is always the next one however, then it's trivial to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hZXUK/2/)

```
var start = { end_lat: 1, end_lng: 1 },
    end = { start_lat: 4, start_lng: 4 },
    coordsBetween = [
        { start_lat: 2, start_lng: 2, end_lat: 3, end_lng: 3  },
        { start_lat: 1, start_lng: 1, end_lat: 2, end_lng: 2  },
        { start_lat: 3, start_lng: 3, end_lat: 4, end_lng: 4  }
    ];

function orderedCoords(start, coords) {
    var result = [],
        point = start;

    while (point = coords.filter(function (item) {
        return item.start_lat === point.end_lat
        && item.start_lng === point.end_lng;
    })[0]) {
        result.push(point);
    }   
    return result;
}

console.log(orderedCoords(start, coordsBetween));
```

Basically we find the next `point` that starts where `start` ends and let that `point` become the next `start` until there's no match and at each step we push the point into `result`.

EDIT:

> This would work of the coordinates of the start and end point
>   overlapped, but none of mine do, there is a large gap between them and
>   I need to generate the 'connectors' between them...

I have expanded my first idea by using an [algorithm to calculate the closest point](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) insead of looking for overlapping coords.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hZXUK/4/)

```
var start = { end_lat: 1, end_lng: 1 },
    end = { start_lat: 4, start_lng: 4 },
    segments = [
        { start_lat: 2, start_lng: 2, end_lat: 3, end_lng: 3  },
        { start_lat: 1, start_lng: 1, end_lat: 2, end_lng: 2  },
        { start_lat: 3, start_lng: 3, end_lat: 4, end_lng: 4  }
    ];

function orderedSegments(start, segments) {
    var result = [],
        segment = start,
        i;

    while ((i = indexOfClosestSegment(segment, segments)) !== -1) {
        result.push(segment = segments.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    }

    return result;
}

function indexOfClosestSegment(segment, segments) {
    var i = 0,
        len = segments.length,
        segIndex = -1,
        tempDistance, smallestDistance;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (
            (tempDistance = distanceBetween(segment, segments[i])) < smallestDistance 
            || typeof smallestDistance === 'undefined') {
            smallestDistance = tempDistance;
            segIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return segIndex;        
}

function distanceBetween(segmentA, segmentB) {
    return Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(segmentB.start_lat - segmentA.end_lat, 2) 
        + Math.pow(segmentB.start_lng - segmentA.end_lng, 2)
    );
}

console.log(orderedSegments(start, segments));
```

> **Notice that the points are geo coordinates and you will need to use a
>   spherical distance algorithm, not the trivial pythagoras. I think GM
>   provides such helper functions for their data structures; of course
>   the algorithm will still work with a different distanceBetween
>   implementation. – *@Bergi***

Comment: Thanks plalx, but it's not exactly what I'm after. This would work of the coordinates of the start and end point overlapped, but none of mine do, there is a large gap between them and I need to generate the 'connectors' between them. Here's a picture trying to illustrate a bit better: http://i.imgur.com/k8VZenS.png

Comment: @andro1d I updated my answer accordingly. I hope that it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for! You're a champion.

Comment: Notice that the points are geo coordinates and you will need to use a [spherical distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_distance), not the trivial pythagoras. I think GM provides such helper functions for their data structures; of course your algorithm will still work with a different `distanceBetween` implementation.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I'm using a variation of this distance formula: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

I think DFS is Okay and transfer visited ordered leg list to next recursion.
and in every recursion choose the last leg and recursive with each unvisted legs.